# Logstash output-http return code

Tags: logstash

How to manage logstash output-http return codes? I'm using logstash-output-http to post data to a restful webservice. Since http may result in application failure (code >= 400) how can i handle this scenario via logstash ?

my configuration is the following:

```
output {
  http {
    url => "http://bla:8080/restful/endpoint"
    http_method => "post"
    format => message
    content_type => "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    message => '{"json":"here"}'
  }
}
```

suppose you have a `code = 500` and you want to eventually deliver such message, how you would do that?

Answer (score 0):

[The code](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-http/blob/master/lib/logstash/outputs/http.rb#L124) seems to imply that you can look in your log file.

There's [an issue](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-http/issues/28) to retry them.

Comment: No workarunds? is the possibility to add an if return!=200 { out {file {}} } ?